# How do i assign the reqOpenorder (from IBrokers package) results to a matrix?

Tags: r, ibrokers

The results from the `reqOpenOrders` are given below

```
**reqOpenOrders(tws)**                           
TWS Message: 2 3 399 Order Message:                     
Warning: Your order size is below the EUR 20000 IdealPro minimum and will be routed as an odd lot order.  
TWS OrderStatus: orderId=3 status=PreSubmitted filled=0 remaining=1 averageFillPrice=0  
TWS OrderStatus: orderId=3 status=Submitted filled=0 remaining=1 averageFillPrice=0  
TWS OrderStatus: orderId=3 status=Submitted filled=0 remaining=1 averageFillPrice=0  
TWS OrderStatus: orderId=3 status=Submitted filled=0 remaining=1 averageFillPrice=0  
TWS OrderStatus: orderId=3 status=Submitted filled=0 remaining=1 averageFillPrice=0  
TWS Execution: orderId=3 time=2012-08-29 15:38:48 side=BOT shares=1 symbol=EUR conId=12087792 price=1.25580
```

But how do I get the above results in a vector/ matrix ?

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2012q1/009563.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was resolved. You might want to take a look, the solution creates a list with the open orders data which you can organize any way you want: [R IBrokers reqOpenOrders hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703679/r-ibrokers-reqopenorders-hangs)